# Is it possible for a slack bot to edit the message on basis of a emoticon?

Tags: bots, slack, slack-api

I want my slack bot to edit the original message (basically modify it).To trigger bot i would like to use an emoticon.

so the flow would be user post the message -> if user wants to use bot press a reaction -> once bot is triggered modify or edit the message with the custom content of bot.

for trigger i think this the API i would need https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.get but is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api you have mentioned is for fetching the reactions associated with a message/post.

What you actually need is an event to be captured when a reaction is added to the message.

Here is the api that solves the purpose:
https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added

You can now implement the business logic based on the event payload.

Sample Payload:

```
{
"type": "reaction_added",
"user": "U024BE7LH",
"reaction": "thumbsup",
"item_user": "U0G9QF9C6",
"item": {
    "type": "message",
    "channel": "C0G9QF9GZ",
    "ts": "1360782400.498405"
},
    "event_ts": "1360782804.083113"
}
```

To update the message, you can use `chat.update` api:

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update

you'll need : 
 ***token**: 'bot token' or 'user token' with required `chat:write` scope  
**channel & timestamp** details : you can find in payload of 'reaction_added' payload.*

**Note:** 
You cannot edit a message sent by another user, unless you have the 'User token'. https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types#user

Comment: Thank you for the help but what abut the part `want my slack bot to edit the original message (basically modify it)` because after event capturing i need to edit the original message of the user by bot

Comment: I've updated the answer with required details.

Comment: This helped a lot :)